# reading string from another component

Tags: reactjs

I have two components 1. keypad.jsx 2.caldisplay.jsx
When a button is clicked on the keypad i pass a string to the function handleclick and it reutrns it as num .
I want to use that 'num' is 'caldisplay' component to display the output.

How do I access the handleclick function or num itself in caldisplay ?

I tried importing handleclick from '.handleclick' and the using that in my div but nothing happened and instead whole app.jsx stopped working

This is caldisplay.jsx :-

```
import React from 'react'
import './style.css'
import {handleclick} from './keypad'
function caldisplay() {
  return (
    <div className='display'>
      {handleclick}
    </div>
  )
}

export default caldisplay
```

This is keypad.jsx

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import './style.css'
function keypad() {

   const handleclick = (num)=>{
    
    console.log("the button clicked was" + num );
    return(num)
    
   }
  return (
    <div className='keypad'>
        <div onClick={()=>{
            handleclick("%")
        }} className=' percentage button'>%</div>
        <div className=' Clearall button'>CE</div>
        <div className=' Clear button'>C</div>
        <div className=' Delete button'>
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" class="lucide lucide-delete"><path d="M20 5H9l-7 7 7 7h11a2 2 0 0 0 2-2V7a2 2 0 0 0-2-2Z"/><line x1="18" x2="12" y1="9" y2="15"/><line x1="12" x2="18" y1="9" y2="15"/></svg>
        </div>
        <div className=' inverse button'>1/x</div>
        <div className=' square button'>x²</div>
        <div className=' sqroot button'>²√x</div>
        <div className=' division button'>/</div>
        <div className=' seven button'>7</div>
        <div className=' eight button'>8</div>
        <div className=' nine button'>9</div>
        <div className='multiply button'>X</div>
        <div className=' four button'>4</div>
        <div className=' five button'>5</div>
        <div className=' six button'>6</div>
        <div className=' minus button'>-</div>
        <div className=' one button'>1</div>
        <div className=' two button'>2</div>
        <div className=' three button'>3</div>
        <div className=' plus button'>+</div>
        <div className=' negate button'>+/-</div>
        <div className=' zero button'>0</div>
        <div className=' dot button'>.</div>
        <div className=' equalsto button'>=</div>
        

    </div>
  )
}

export default keypad
```

Comment: The usual pattern here is to elevate the data to the shared parent component and distribute it from there. Data down, events up. You can share data between sibling components as a last resort, but you can't call functions like you're trying to do here. Event handlers should be local to the component they're within.

Comment: how do i share that string between these components then ?

Comment: [Many similar questions](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+share+data+between+react+components)

Comment: Is there some reason you don't want to take my advice and move the data up to the App or other shared ancestor component?

Comment: because i dont know how to move the data to another component

Comment: That's usually a poor reason to not follow best practice. I suggest stepping back and doing some learning. https://react.dev/learn#sharing-data-between-components

Comment: I knew I lacked some crucial info since I have only been learning React for 3 days

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the number which you click in the Keypad component and do sth.(like rendering or do some math work) in the Caldisplay component.

You can write a function in Caldisplay component and pass it to Keypad component.like

```
function caldisplay() {
  // if you want to render the clickedNum
  const [clickedNum, setClickedNum] = useState('');
  const handleClick = useCallBack((num) => {
    setClickedNum(num);
  })
  return (
    <>
      <div className='display'>
       {clickedNum}
      </div>
      <keypad handleClick={handleClick} />
    </>
  )
}
```